# Different results from polr depending on whether categorical variable is encoded as string or number

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-encoding, polr

Our aim is to find out whether the general self-efficacy (GSE), as measured by the "New General Self-efficacy Scale" (1-10), changes in participants after the completion of a specific task which comes in two conditions. In one case, the the task is posed in the `future simple` tense, and in the other in the `future perfect` tense. We measured GSE both before and after the administration of the procedure, and are now trying to find out the contributions of each factor in play using `polr`.

The factors are `Condition`, i.e. the type of task administered, and the `GSE score` from before the completion of the task. The two `GSE scores`, before and after, were centered before fitting the model, because the lower values were not contained in our sample.

The model in question is the following:

```
gse.model = polr(factor(GSE_median_after, ordered=TRUE) ~ GSE_median_before * factor(Condition),
                 Hess=TRUE, method = c("logistic"), data=data2_numerical)
summary(gse.model)
```

Now, we have found out that, depending on whether our independent categorical variable `Condition` is encoded either numerically, `0` and `1`, or as a string `simple` and `perfect`, the results differ significantly. In both cases, `Condition` is turned into a factor before the model is fit, so one would not expect to see any differences. Everything else stayed the same between the two fits.

The results are the following:

**1. **With numerical encoding:****

```
polr(formula = factor(GSE_median_after, ordered = TRUE) ~ GSE_median_before * 
    factor(Condition), data = data2_numerical, Hess = TRUE, method = c("logistic"))

Coefficients:
                                        Value Std. Error  t value
GSE_median_before                     1.95214     0.5246  3.72113
factor(Condition)1                   -0.03605     0.5625 -0.06409
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)1  0.87851     0.5867  1.49735

Intercepts:
                                      Value   Std. Error t value
-3.2962962962963|-2.7962962962963     -6.1735  1.1191    -5.5162
-2.7962962962963|-2.2962962962963     -5.6928  1.0403    -5.4720
-2.2962962962963|-1.7962962962963     -4.8348  0.9258    -5.2222
-1.7962962962963|-0.796296296296297   -4.4565  0.8714    -5.1143
-0.796296296296297|-0.296296296296297 -3.0280  0.6887    -4.3967
-0.296296296296297|0.203703703703703  -0.4301  0.4380    -0.9821
0.203703703703703|0.703703703703703    0.9014  0.4489     2.0081
0.703703703703703|1.7037037037037      3.6064  0.7120     5.0649
1.7037037037037|2.7037037037037        5.7221  1.2031     4.7560

Residual Deviance: 146.4581 
AIC: 170.4581 
> 
> (gse_table <- coef(summary(gse.model)))
                                            Value Std. Error     t value
GSE_median_before                      1.95214421  0.5246100  3.72113430
factor(Condition)1                    -0.03605171  0.5625101 -0.06409078
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)1   0.87851094  0.5867092  1.49735337
-3.2962962962963|-2.7962962962963     -6.17346881  1.1191431 -5.51624609
-2.7962962962963|-2.2962962962963     -5.69278700  1.0403435 -5.47202611
-2.2962962962963|-1.7962962962963     -4.83479423  0.9258172 -5.22219090
-1.7962962962963|-0.796296296296297   -4.45652252  0.8713845 -5.11430115
-0.796296296296297|-0.296296296296297 -3.02799935  0.6886978 -4.39670229
-0.296296296296297|0.203703703703703  -0.43014013  0.4379980 -0.98205950
0.203703703703703|0.703703703703703    0.90140943  0.4488822  2.00812019
0.703703703703703|1.7037037037037      3.60636799  0.7120303  5.06490820
1.7037037037037|2.7037037037037        5.72207373  1.2031335  4.75597584
> 
> ## calculate and store p values
> p_gse <- pnorm(abs(gse_table[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
> 
> ## combined table
> (gse_table <- cbind(gse_table, "p value" = p_gse))
                                            Value Std. Error     t value      p value
GSE_median_before                      1.95214421  0.5246100  3.72113430 1.983299e-04
factor(Condition)1                    -0.03605171  0.5625101 -0.06409078 9.488979e-01
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)1   0.87851094  0.5867092  1.49735337 1.343013e-01
-3.2962962962963|-2.7962962962963     -6.17346881  1.1191431 -5.51624609 3.463172e-08
-2.7962962962963|-2.2962962962963     -5.69278700  1.0403435 -5.47202611 4.449193e-08
-2.2962962962963|-1.7962962962963     -4.83479423  0.9258172 -5.22219090 1.768185e-07
-1.7962962962963|-0.796296296296297   -4.45652252  0.8713845 -5.11430115 3.149046e-07
-0.796296296296297|-0.296296296296297 -3.02799935  0.6886978 -4.39670229 1.099079e-05
-0.296296296296297|0.203703703703703  -0.43014013  0.4379980 -0.98205950 3.260705e-01
0.203703703703703|0.703703703703703    0.90140943  0.4488822  2.00812019 4.463052e-02
0.703703703703703|1.7037037037037      3.60636799  0.7120303  5.06490820 4.085972e-07
1.7037037037037|2.7037037037037        5.72207373  1.2031335  4.75597584 1.974901e-06
> (ci <- confint(gse.model)) # default method gives profiled CIs
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                                          2.5 %   97.5 %
GSE_median_before                     0.9606885 3.031922
factor(Condition)1                   -1.1464618 1.074708
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)1 -0.2447007 2.072207
> confint.default(gse.model) # CIs assuming normality
                                          2.5 %   97.5 %
GSE_median_before                     0.9239275 2.980361
factor(Condition)1                   -1.1385512 1.066448
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)1 -0.2714179 2.028440
> 
> ## odds ratios
> exp(coef(gse.model))
                   GSE_median_before                   factor(Condition)1 GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)1 
                           7.0437747                            0.9645904                            2.4073124 
> 
> ## OR and CI
> exp(cbind(OR = coef(gse.model), ci))
                                            OR     2.5 %    97.5 %
GSE_median_before                    7.0437747 2.6134954 20.737053
factor(Condition)1                   0.9645904 0.3177591  2.929137
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)1 2.4073124 0.7829389  7.942334
```

**2. **With string encoding:****

```
Coefficients:
                                            Value Std. Error  t value
GSE_median_before                          2.8302     0.4773  5.92971
factor(Condition)simple                    0.0359     0.5625  0.06382
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)simple -0.8782     0.5867 -1.49685

Intercepts:
                                      Value   Std. Error t value
-3.2962962962963|-2.7962962962963     -6.1364  1.0399    -5.9008
-2.7962962962963|-2.2962962962963     -5.6555  0.9568    -5.9109
-2.2962962962963|-1.7962962962963     -4.7979  0.8451    -5.6773
-1.7962962962963|-0.796296296296297   -4.4196  0.7948    -5.5608
-0.796296296296297|-0.296296296296297 -2.9917  0.6513    -4.5932
-0.296296296296297|0.203703703703703  -0.3942  0.5046    -0.7813
0.203703703703703|0.703703703703703    0.9372  0.5239     1.7890
0.703703703703703|1.7037037037037      3.6420  0.6819     5.3412
1.7037037037037|2.7037037037037        5.7575  1.1445     5.0308

Residual Deviance: 146.4581 
AIC: 170.4581 
> 
> (gse_table <- coef(summary(gse.model)))
                                                Value Std. Error     t value
GSE_median_before                          2.83021077  0.4772933  5.92971031
factor(Condition)simple                    0.03589579  0.5624803  0.06381697
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)simple -0.87815558  0.5866672 -1.49685485
-3.2962962962963|-2.7962962962963         -6.13637830  1.0399306 -5.90075777
-2.7962962962963|-2.2962962962963         -5.65546851  0.9567837 -5.91091620
-2.2962962962963|-1.7962962962963         -4.79788250  0.8450923 -5.67734727
-1.7962962962963|-0.796296296296297       -4.41957290  0.7947786 -5.56075955
-0.796296296296297|-0.296296296296297     -2.99170505  0.6513392 -4.59316010
-0.296296296296297|0.203703703703703      -0.39424682  0.5046339 -0.78125307
0.203703703703703|0.703703703703703        0.93723976  0.5238860  1.78901464
0.703703703703703|1.7037037037037          3.64197339  0.6818589  5.34124228
1.7037037037037|2.7037037037037            5.75753332  1.1444552  5.03080687
> 
> ## calculate and store p values
> p_gse <- pnorm(abs(gse_table[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
> 
> ## combined table
> (gse_table <- cbind(gse_table, "p value" = p_gse))
                                                Value Std. Error     t value      p value
GSE_median_before                          2.83021077  0.4772933  5.92971031 3.034696e-09
factor(Condition)simple                    0.03589579  0.5624803  0.06381697 9.491160e-01
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)simple -0.87815558  0.5866672 -1.49685485 1.344310e-01
-3.2962962962963|-2.7962962962963         -6.13637830  1.0399306 -5.90075777 3.618358e-09
-2.7962962962963|-2.2962962962963         -5.65546851  0.9567837 -5.91091620 3.402101e-09
-2.2962962962963|-1.7962962962963         -4.79788250  0.8450923 -5.67734727 1.367996e-08
-1.7962962962963|-0.796296296296297       -4.41957290  0.7947786 -5.56075955 2.686031e-08
-0.796296296296297|-0.296296296296297     -2.99170505  0.6513392 -4.59316010 4.365839e-06
-0.296296296296297|0.203703703703703      -0.39424682  0.5046339 -0.78125307 4.346537e-01
0.203703703703703|0.703703703703703        0.93723976  0.5238860  1.78901464 7.361246e-02
0.703703703703703|1.7037037037037          3.64197339  0.6818589  5.34124228 9.231179e-08
1.7037037037037|2.7037037037037            5.75753332  1.1444552  5.03080687 4.884200e-07
> (ci <- confint(gse.model)) # default method gives profiled CIs
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                                              2.5 %   97.5 %
GSE_median_before                          1.963800 3.848268
factor(Condition)simple                   -1.074707 1.146461
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)simple -2.072205 0.244699
> confint.default(gse.model) # CIs assuming normality
                                              2.5 %    97.5 %
GSE_median_before                          1.894733 3.7656884
factor(Condition)simple                   -1.066545 1.1383370
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)simple -2.028002 0.2716909
> 
> ## odds ratios
> exp(coef(gse.model))
                        GSE_median_before                   factor(Condition)simple GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)simple 
                               16.9490327                                 1.0365478                                 0.4155487 
> 
> ## OR and CI
> exp(cbind(OR = coef(gse.model), ci))
                                                  OR     2.5 %    97.5 %
GSE_median_before                         16.9490327 7.1263533 46.911751
factor(Condition)simple                    1.0365478 0.3413977  3.147037
GSE_median_before:factor(Condition)simple  0.4155487 0.1259078  1.277237
```

How is it possible that the results differ to this extent, as one can see for example in the **ODDS RATIO** (OR) at the end, which is around *7.04* in the numerical encoding, and *16.94* in the string encoding?

And more importantly: which of the results is correct?

Thank you very much for your time!!

Comment: simple should correspond to 0 and perfect should correspond to 1. In the numerical case the first level is 0 while in the string case the first level is perfect. Order the factor levels in both cases so they match.

Comment: Oh my god, yeah. We're feeling kinda stupid right now...